# Is it beneficial to treat a burn with ice?

Tags: ice

I've often heard people, including my own mother, tell me that treating a burn with ice is beneficial: presumably, to the pain level, and swelling. Is that so? Does it really make a difference?

Comment: Can you please point to a source that claims that you should cool a burn with ice?

Comment: From:- Burns FAQ **Don't Use Ice**It has lateral heat stored in it and may also cause a Cold Burn!

Comment: @ShubhBhatia Can you provide a link for the "Burns FAQ" you cited? Also, what is "lateral heat" and a "cold burn"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Mayo Clinic's burn first aid](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/first-aid-burns/FA00022):

> **Cool the burn**. Hold the burned area under **cool (not cold) running water** for 10 or 15 minutes or until the pain subsides. If this is impractical, immerse the burn in cool water or cool it with cold compresses. Cooling the burn reduces swelling by conducting heat away from the skin. **Don't put ice on the burn**.
>
> [...]
>
> Caution
>
> **Don't use ice**. Putting ice directly on a burn can cause a person's body to become too cold and cause further damage to the wound.

From [WebMD](http://firstaid.webmd.com/tc/burns-home-treatment):

> Do not use ice.
>
> [...]
>
> Do not put ice or butter on the burned area.

From [*Ambulatory Management of Burns*](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2000/1101/p2015.html) in American Family Physician:

> Ice application should be avoided.

Comment: Can you update this to include why ice shouldn't be used?